# why symbol exported from linux kernel cannot be used by module?

Tags: linux, kernel

I define a variablity in kernel .c file,for example socket.c，and export it as follows:

```
int abcdefg;
EXPORT_SYMBOL(abcdefg);
```

Then compiles it with "sudo make bzImage" and reboot.But when I use it in my own module,when insmod the module ,it says "Unknown symbol in module".

So I go to see the symbol list. When use

```
cat /proc/kallsyms | grep "abcdefg"
```

there is nothing.

When use

```
nm vmlinux | grep "abcdefg"
```

there is `c1d2b700 B abcdefg`

How should I do to use the symbol in my own module?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zv5SM.png

Comment: It sounds like you're not actually running the new kernel.

Comment: But the symbol list has the variablity，which is not defined by old kernel.

Comment: Yes，you are right! I forget  to update the kernel with "make install". Now use "cat /proc/kallsyms | grep "abcdefg"", I can get "B abcdefg". I see when the symbol is export from module, it is "T string". B means "External zeroed data". What that means? Does it matter?

Comment: Your symbol, `abcdefg` is not initialized, so by default it is zeroed. It will be put in the `.bss` section.

Comment: ok, very thank you~

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not actually running the new kernel. – Jonathon Reinhart

Yes，you are right! I forget to update the kernel with "make install". – jenny